# Launching a native application from a link of website on iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari

I have a query regarding launching a native application from a link of website on iPhone.

I will explain.
Generally a web based application is used to work online without using any feature of iPhone device (such as GPS, Camera, Accelerometer etc.)

I have a iPhone specific website which performs many tasks online.

Now while keeping all the functionality same, I want to add a feature of taking a picture from iPhone in-built camera.
i.e. when user clicks a button on website "Take Picture", my native application should be launched, which will take a picture and do specific tasks..

How to capture a event of button click which is performed on website?
Should I use UIWebView or Safari?

I know that using URL Scheme we can launch Safari from native application.
But how to achieve the opposite as explained above?

All other functionality works great on website, so I don't want to convert the whole website into native application.
(Otherwise I will have to deal with web services). Only this functionality needs to be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register a URL Handler, then have a link on your site to myapphandle://some.parameters.here/

A la: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It worked great.


I have another one query.

What if I want to load my custom view on click of a link of webView?

I will explain.
I want my native app to have a webview (which will show a webSite) and on one of the clicks of website, I want to come back to my native application and load another view.

As per earlier question, current application will quit and new will be launched. I want the control to be in the same application?

Is there any way that we can acheive it?

Can we get current address of webview and use that? 

please help.

Comment: Amitkumar, look into the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on android as well?